# Check if user connecting is not admin or user

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I check if user is not Admin or User? I need this function to determine if the username connecting is anything but Admin or User.

Thanks for the help.

```
 If (CurrentUser.UserName <> "Admin") Or (CurrentUser.UserName <> "User")
```

Comment: User name alone is pretty weak. If you used ASP.NET authentication then I'd use User.IsInRole("Administrators")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using an identity model at all in your application?  If you're using Forms Authentication for example, and using the Universal Membership Provider (default membership provider in ASP.NET), then that linkage will help you.  From there, you can use the "IsInRole" method of the User object, and add\remove users from the appropriate roles.  Start with this article, and Google from there for more info on using Universal Membership: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprincipal.isinrole(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprincipal.isinrole%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)